# Django ORM: Aggregating annotations raises DatabaseError

Tags: django-orm

If I have a model **Book** defined as:

```
class Book(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   pages = models.IntegerField()
   price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
   rating = models.FloatField()
   pubdate = models.DateField()
```

and I run the query:

```
Book.objects.values('rating').annotate(books_per_rating=Count('id')).aggregate(Max('books_per_rating'))
```

I get a **DatabaseError**.

According to this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations, Django supports aggregating annotations. But in the example given in the link itself, they annotate over a **QuerySet** which in turn returns a **QuerySet** (and not **ValuesQuerySet**), so aggregate method runs successfully. But in my example aggregating a **ValuesQuerySet** raises a **DatabaseError**.

Is it a bug in Django? Because if Django does not support aggregation over **ValuesQuerySet** then it should raise an exception at Django level (not **DatabaseError**).

**Update**:

This bug has been solved here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20782

Comment: Also interestingly if do:
`Book.objects.values('rating').aggregate(Max('rating'))`
It returns an empty dict without performing any DB query!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you've ran into a bug. You should log this on the django [trac instance](https://code.djangoproject.com/newticket).

Be specific about which DB Backend you're using. I'm testing against sqlite at the moment, since I don't currently have access to a different backend. I mention this because I've seen usage of `values().aggregate()` working while searching for an answer to this question - so it may just be a bug in the SQLite sql compiler that django uses.

Here is the test I was using, and the output from the generated query.

```
>>> Stats.objects.values('created').annotate(num_days=Count('id')).aggregate(Max('num_days'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
DatabaseError: near "FROM": syntax error
>>> print connection.queries[-1]
{u'time': u'0.000', u'sql': u'SELECT  FROM (SELECT "scratch_stats"."created" AS "created", COUNT("scratch_stats"."id") AS "num_days" FROM "scratch_stats" GROUP BY "scratch_stats"."created") subquery'}
```

Edit:

Just tried the same thing with postgres, and same error. Appears you can't use `aggregate` with a `ValuesQuerySet`.

Fails on django 1.4, 1.5 and 1.6.

Comment: and if you give me 30 minutes I'll try the test on postgres

Comment: I was using postgres, but got the have error on sqllit (as you are also getting). Thanks for help :), I'll create a new ticket for this.